# How to count conditions across a row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 0, 3],
    'b': [1, 2, 0, 0],
    'c': [5, 2, 0, 3],
    'd': [0, 3, 7, 1]
})
```

I would now like to create another column `n` which counts how many values of columns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` are `> 0`.

By hand we need to do:

```
df['n'] = [3, 2, 3, 3]
```

I don't need to state that this is unhandy for larger frames. I know we can select the rows we are interested with `df.a > 0`, ..., `df.d > 0`.

Unfortunately I am not able to convert the provided `bool` values to `0` and `1` and sum them.

```
df['n'] = df. a > 0 + df.b > 0 + df.c > 0 + df.d > 0
```

Throws

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

**How do I correct this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform a list comprehension, looping over the columns and then use a boolean condition on that column, drop the values that don't meet the condition and call count:

```
In [360]:

[df.loc[df[col]>0,col].dropna().count() for col in df]
Out[360]:
[3, 2, 3, 3]
```

This would yield the column:

```
In [361]:

df['n'] = [df.loc[df[col]>0,col].dropna().count() for col in df]
df
Out[361]:
   a  b  c  d  n
0  1  1  5  0  3
1  2  2  2  3  2
2  0  0  0  7  3
3  3  0  3  1  3
```

At this stage it may make sense to label your rows to the column names so that you `n` makes sense.

**EDIT**

I realised on my way to lunch that there was a simpler method just calling [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html#pandas.DataFrame.count):

```
In [365]:

df[df>0].count()
Out[365]:
a    3
b    2
c    3
d    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Actually I just realised that df[df >0].count(axis = 1) should work, I'm having lunch at the moment will check and update